# Media queries only applied for authenticated users

Tags: theming

i'm working on a responsive theme using compass / susy, and i had issues on application of media queries.For example, images weren't responsive on mobile, or weren't on full size for desktop.
i did test on different browser and the only one that work were one for connected user.so i did connect me under others browser and media queries were applied.
so what can i do to fix this uge problem ?

thanks

Comment: Looks like yet another anonymous cache problem.

Answer (score 1):

As Molot commented it is just a cache problem. You need to clear your browser cache to get the updated css. Another trick that works for me is to add a query string in the URL (e.g `http://example.com/node/test?awy`). You may need to turn off the css aggregation under `Performance` page to make sure that you will get the updated css and not the cached copy.

You can use Drush to clear your cache by using `drush cc all`.